# .Net: authorize user by voice sample

Tags: c#, .net, voice-recognition

I have a .net desktop application and authorization should be done via user voice sample. 
 Found nothing suitable in [Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=office.14).aspx)
[Here](http://www.generation5.org/content/2004/noReco.asp) is a good example, but it looks obsolete

Is there a way to recognize user by voice sample by a pass phrase or in general by any phrase?

Comment: Speech recognition and identifying different people by their voice are completely different things. What you want is something like https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/speaker-recognition-api to identify who is speaking.

Comment: Why does it "look obsolete"? Perhaps you are looking at the *wrong* SDK? That's the API for Speech Server. Check the [Speech API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361625.aspx). Also note that in UWP and Phone applications, the [APIs are different](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/speech-recognition)

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Could you please post your comment as an answer?  This is exactly what I was looking for.